# Space before the "?", normally unbreakable with babel-french, breakable with listings' breaklines option

Tags: spacing, listings, typewriter, babel-french

With `babel-french`, the space before the question mark is normally unbreakable.

But, as shown by the MWE below (compiled with `pdflatex`, `xelatex` or `lualatex`), the `breaklines` option of the `listings` package can, in some circumstances, have the same effect as if this space would be breakable.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage[showframe,paperheight=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  breaklines
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\hspace*{14.95cm}\texttt{m}?

\hspace*{14.95cm}\lstinline[breaklines=false]|m|?

\hspace*{14.95cm}\lstinline|m|?
\end{document}
```

[image]

Strange, isn't it?

Comment: I have changed `ECM` (exemple complet minimal, I presume?) to the English `MWE` …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the same issue occurs also *without* babel-french.

`listings`'option `breaklines` enables line breaking *anywhere*, line breaking can be restricted to occur only on spaces (except unbreakable ones)  with option `breakatwhitespace`.

The issue mentioned by Denis vanishes when `breakatwhitespace` is added to `\lstset{}` with and without babel-french.